# Meaning of uniformly Cesàro summable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series, weak-convergence, cesaro-summable

There is a theorem like:    `The Fourier series of a continuous function` $f(x)$ `defined on` $[-\pi,\pi]$ `of period` $2\pi$ `is Uniformly Cesàro summable to` $f(x)$.    Now, I don't know the definition of Uniform Cesaro Summability.   Can anyone explain this to me and give the proof of this theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

If $(S_n)$ is the partial sum sequence of the Fourier series of $f$ then uniform Cesaro summability means $\sigma_n \to f$ uniformly, where $\sigma_n =\frac {S_0+S_1+...+S_n} {n+1}$.  This result is called Fejer's Theorem and you can find it in many books as well as Wikipedia. See, for example,  6.1.1, p. 87 of Edward's Fourier Series. (Take $k=0$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n f$ be equal to n-nth partiał sum od Fourier series od tej function $f$, i.e, $$S_n f (x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k\cos kx + b_k\sin kx )$$.
Ten thę Cęsaro partiał sum arę equał to $$c_n f(x)=\frac{S_1 f(x) +...+S_n f(x)}{n}.$$

And Thę Theorem says that $$c_n f\to f$$  uniformły on $[-\pi ,\pi].$